# How to create Index with first letter capitalized using xindy

Tags: xetex, indexing, xindy, imakeidx, makeindex

I'm using xindy to make my Index page. Is it possible to style it in such way that each first word in letter group will have first letter capitalized? I would like to have something like this:

```
Tabela, 120
telefon, 82
tkanina, 65

Wanna, 43
wek, 56
...
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1]

\def\myFirstUpper#1{\expandafter\MakeUppercase #1} %
\long\def\lettergroup#1\item{\item\myFirstUpper}
\let\lettergroupDefault\lettergroup

\begin{document}
foo\index{tabela}. foo\index{telefon}. foo\index{tkanina}, asdf\index{wanna} asd\index{wek}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

It produces:
[image]